# Pylons and Flex 3

Tags: python, apache-flex, pylons, twisted

Has anyone used Python/Pylons as the server backend for a Flex 3 application? Does anyone have any thoughts on how well this would work? I read Bruce Eckel's article about tying Flex 3 to Twisted, and I've done Twisted programming, but for just a web service I think Pylons is simpler to use.

Thanks in advance,

Doug

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on webapp which has client-side UI coded in Flex 3 and backend is Pylons app. Our client communicates with backend using HTTP GET and POST requests, POST request bodies and all response bodies carry data in JSON format. Works well, just few gotchas:

- Flex apps cannot do PUT and DELETE requests. We work around this by doing POST requests and specifying the "real" intended method in `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header. Then we have some extra routes in routing configuration that handle these requests and treat them as normal PUTs and GETs.
- Flex apps can send custom HTTP headers but cannot read custom headers received from server (well they can on IE, but cannot on Firefox and Chrome, IIRC).